# mvvmcross ViewModel's init() is called at last

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a DetailViewModel which has several custom buttons and initialize them in Init().

```
public class DetailViewModel{
    ...
    public async void Init(DetailParameter params){
       ...
       CustomButtons.Add(new CustomButton(this, "1"));            //3
       CustomButtons.Add(new CustomButton(this, "2"));
       ...
    }
}
```

Then in the detail view, I have several buttons and bind them with custom buttons in DetailViewModel.

```
public partial class DetailView{
   private List<CustomButton> m_customButtons;
   public List<CustomButton> CutomButtons{
      get { return m_customButtons; }
      set { m_customButtons = value;                             //2
            foreach(CustomButton button in m_customButtons){
                UIButton myButton = new UIButton ();
                Add(myButton);
            }
      }
   }

   public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<DetailView, DetailViewModel>();
        set.Bind (this).For (v=>v.CustomButtons).To (vm=>vm.CustomButtons);//1
        set.Apply ();
    }
 }
```

The problem is that ViewModel's Init() is called at last.
So always m_customButtons has set by 0 count, then ViewModel's Init() is called.
I know about CIRS, but how can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty you could do to change your binding to make it work in this `async` scenario - including using observable collections.

However, the simplest route in your current setup might just be to change the entire `CustomButtons` list in your ViewModel instead - e.g. something like:

```
   var customButtons = new List<CustomButton>() {
      new CustomButton(this, "1"),
      new CustomButton(this, "2")
   };
   CustomButtons = customButtons;
   RaisePropertyChanged(() => CustomButtons);
```

In this "one-off" scenario, this implementation should work for you. For more advanced dynamic scenarios, it might be worthwhile looking at `INotifyCollectionChanged` implementations too.